# Android Email vs MMS Raw Attachment?

Tags: android, email, android-intent, mms

I have this code to send an **emai with an `audio attachment`** that is coming from the `raw folder`:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
i.setType("Audio/basic");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "mySubject");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "myBody");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("android.resource://[my_package]/raw/sound"));
startActivity(i);
```

This code works fine.

I tried to adapt the same code so that I can send **MMS message with `audio attachment`** from the `raw folder`.

I came up with this:

```
String uri= "mmsto:";
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.parse(uri));
i.putExtra("sms_body", "myBody");
i.putExtra("compose_mode", true);
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse"android.resource://[my_package]/raw/sound"));
startActivity(i);
```

The code opens an SMS application. However, there isn't any attachment to the message !

Am I doing it right? Please help me with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To those who might be interested:

MMS Functionality is a bit unreliable, not well-documented feature in Android. So, the existed solutions are supposed to work but they will not work all the time on all the devices. You can't depend on them, yet.